# Davening for the demise of the wicked

Tags: tefilla, death, evil-resha

Is it a mitzvah,permissible, forbidden to daven for a Jewish wicked person to die? If the wicked person is someone who is trying convert Jews to Christianity would that make a difference? I am looking for some sources from the Talmud, Rishonim and/or Achronim.

Comment: We pray for this three times a day "the apostates should have no hope and all the heretics should immediately be destroyed"

Comment: Why not pray for him to change his ways, or be ineffective in his efforts, as per B'rurya's response to R. Meir (Berakhot 10b)
מאי דעתך? - משום דכתיב: יתמו חטאים, מי כתיב חוטאים? חטאים כתיב! ועוד, שפיל לסיפיה דקרא: ורשעים עוד אינם, כיון דיתמו חטאים - ורשעים עוד אינם? אלא, בעי רחמי עלויהו דלהדרו בתשובה - ורשעים עוד אינם. בעא רחמי עלויהו והדרו בתשובה

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31452/why-do-we-pray-for-g-d-to-smash-down-our-fellow-jews

Comment: Consider Tehilim 115:8. כְּ֭מוֹהֶם יִהְי֣וּ עֹשֵׂיהֶ֑ם כֹּ֭ל אֲשֶׁר־בֹּטֵ֣חַ בָּהֶֽם׃

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76568 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28982